# permuting columns of a doubly stochastic matrix so that product of the diagonal entries is positive

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm reading the book Matrix Analysis 2ed. by Horn and Johnson and stumbled upon a lemma for proving the Birkhoff-von-Neumann theorem. In short, the lemma says that if $A \in \mathbb{M}_n$ is non-identity doubly stochastic matrix, then there exists a nonidentity permutation $\sigma$ such that $\prod_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i \sigma(i)} > 0$. The authors prove this by contradiction. Assume that $\prod_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i \sigma(i)} = 0$ for all non-identity $\sigma$. They then say that by Leibniz's formula, the characteristic polynomial for $A$ is
$$
p(t) = \prod_{i}(t - a_{i i}) + \sum_{\sigma \neq id} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i} (-a_{i\sigma(i)}) = \prod_{i} (t - a_{i i}),
$$
and then they go on to argue that $a_{i i}$ are eigenvalues of $A$.

**Question**. I can see that the equality holds for the simple case $n = 2$, but don't really get how it holds for general $n$. I fail to see why there is no $t$ in the first equality above. Shouldn't the second term be
$$
\sum_{\sigma \neq id} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i} (t \delta_{i\sigma(i)} -a_{i\sigma(i)}),
$$
where $\delta_{i j} = 1$ for $i = j$ and $\delta_{i j} = 0$ for $i \neq j$? If so, how could you drop the terms where $\sigma(i) = i$?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you mean that the diagonal entries are positive or that their product is?

Comment: @LucaT.Castrillón These two are actually equivalent, since the entries are nonnegative by assumption. I modified the title just to be consistent with description, thanks.

Comment: Ok. I was thinking more generally with possibly negative entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right. The proof in the lemma is unclear if not mistaken. In the first edition, a graph-theoretic proof of Birkhoff’s theorem, which completely bypasses the lemma in question, was used. The authors probably wanted to switch to a slicker proof of Birkhoff’s theorem in the second edition, but ended up with a problematic proof of the lemma.

A proof of the lemma, based on Frobenius-König theorem, can be found in some classic texts such as Marcus & Minc or Berman & Plemmons. This proof seems quite popular.

Comment: Many thanks, I found the graph-theoretic proofs of the lemma quite interesting and understandable.